# Countable dense subset of Baire (ω^ω)

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

> Prove that
> $$
> D = 
> \{ f \in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \mid \exists i \forall j \geq i f(j) = 0 \}
> $$
> is a countable dense subset of $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ (Baire).

Here is the theorem about the Seperability of Baire space. How can I start? Actually isn’t it’s clear that for all s finite sequence there at least one x eventually goes with 0? how can I show it more formally?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! In general you should typeset your questions using mathjax rather than using images. This makes them easier to search, so that future users can find your question too! I've edited your question for you, but in the future you should try to do this yourself ^_^

Comment: thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every basic open set of Baire space is determined by an initial segment.

So every such sets contains (lots of) sequences that are eventually $0$: after the initial segment condition has been satisfied, we're free to choose coordinates..

So the set of eventually $0$ sequences (or eventually $1$ sequences etc) are dense in Baire space (i.e. $\omega^\omega$)

Comment: thank yo su much, so we can choose any constant n after the initiail segment thoug all forms like that so dence in Baire

Comment: @Etü Yes, any pattern that we like in the infinite tail, really.

Comment: appreciated, thx much :)